# Não consigo renderizar html em python 3

Tags: python, template, bottle

Tenho o seguinte app:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from bottle import template, route, run
import html
cabeca = ('''
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>

        <nav id="menu">
            {{menu}}
        </nav>

        <main id="conteudo">
            {{conteudo}}
        </main>

    </body>
</html>
''')
menu = (('add', 'flaticon-add', 'Adicionar'),
('busca', 'flaticon-target', 'Buscar'),
('balanco', 'flaticon-coin', 'Balanço'),
('conf', 'flaticon-settings', 'Configurações'))

def cria_menu():
    bloco = ('<nav id="menu">')
    for item in menu:
        bloco += ('<div class="menu-item">\
        <a class="menu-link" href="{}">\
        <img class="{} menu-icon" alt="{}"/>\
        </a>\
        </div>\
        '.format(item[0], item[1], item[2]))
    bloco += ('</nav>')
    return(bloco)

@route('/')
def index():
    return(template(cabeca, menu = html.unescape(cria_menu())\
    .replace('&lt;', '<')\
    .replace('&gt;', '>')\
    .replace('&quot;', '"'), conteudo = 'Alguma coisa'))

run(port = 8000, debug = True, reloader = True)
```

Não importa o que eu faça, não consigo renderizar a págiina.

Comment: Retorna algum erro ? É importante adicionar informações que ajude a solucionar seu problema ou dúvida. Você pode fazer isso [editando](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/325719/edit) sua pergunta.

Comment: Como já foi citado, seria de extrema importância que fornecesse a saída de erro, debugando você consegue ver isso. Executei seu arquivo no *Python3* e explicitando a importação do `unescape`: `from html import unescape` e me retornou uma saída de texto com o *html* montado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que a sintaxe `{{ variavel }}` existe para incluir texto comum no seu HTML, e não para incluir mais código HTML. Essa sintaxe faz com que o bottle automaticamente "escape" todo o conteúdo da variável para que ele apareça no resultado assim como é, e prevenir ataques XSS caso a variável venha do usuário.

Para incluir um template no outro, o correto seria usar `include()` ou `rebase()` como no [exemplo da documentação](https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/stpl.html#stpl.include).

Mas para um teste rápido, você pode incluir a exclamacão `!` antes do nome da variável, que força o bottle a não "escapar" o conteúdo e deixá-lo como está:

```
    <nav id="menu">
        {{!menu}}
    </nav>

    <main id="conteudo">
        {{!conteudo}}
    </main>
```